# Flutter Firebase - retrieving data using where in a collection with multiple docs

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm trying to retrieve data from FireBase using the input by the user in the search bar.
The db struture is like this:
[DB struture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9svhX.jpg)
Where every doc inside the collection "catalog" have one aditional collection named "recipes" and inside "recipes" are recipes with titles.
[Example DB struture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHCE1.jpg)

How I can compare the input of the user with all recipes inside of all docs?

Currently using this code it works for 1 doc:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFC8U.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want true full text search capabilities you will need to use a tool designed for that problem like [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/enterprise-search/search-applications), [Typesense](https://typesense.org/) or [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/).

Each of these are standalone services that can be used, but have very seamless integrations when using them as part of [Firebase Extensions](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions). Extensions will however need a credit card on file to be enabled.

Note that each of these may have cost implications, and limitations on how to structure your database. Algolia for example requires your text searchable entries to be in one collection.

You might then use a Firestore structure as follows:

`foodTypes > meat > recipes > <recipe Id>`

where meat and recipes are sub collections.